# Laravel Query to get distinct values on a column, but after using orderby to get latest distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5

I want to show only distinct rows from a table, but those values needs to be the latest ones, which i am filtering from date in the table. Here is my query. The result i am getting is the older row from date, the orderby is not working here i guess. please help. I have attached my table.

```
$reports= DB::table('resident_assessment')
          -where('resident_assessment.assessment_date','<=',$date)
          -join('assessment_entry','resident_assessment.assessment_id','=','assessment_entry.assessment_id')
          -orderby('resident_assessment.assessment_date','desc')
          -distinct()->get();
```

[image]

Comment: What's the column type for `assessment_date`? Also maybe you meant `orderBy()` instead of `orderby()`?

Comment: @Mozammil it works as orderby() in laravel. What I need is to get distinct values after ordering.

Comment: Column type for date is `date`

Comment: Forget about laravel for the time being. Focus on getting a working query. To that end, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT RA.* FROM resident_assessment RA INNER JOIN assessment_entry AE ON 
AE.assessment_id = RA.assessment_id
WHERE RA.assessment_date = $date ORDER BY RA.assessment_date desc
```

This is the suitable select statement for your task. This might help you

Comment: I am getting all the rows from this query. What I need is the distinct rows on column name `assessment_id`. How to use `distinct()` or any other method to get the result?

Comment: If you could show us a sample result set you want, we could probably help better.

Comment: @BikramNath  Please change "SELECT DISTINCT RA.* " to "SELECT DISTINCT RA.assessment_id " in order to get what you want.

Comment: @Sachintha Nayanajith Thank You!! It worked like a charm